Why computation of $P(X)$ is hard in posterior?
Let $X$ denotes the input space of dimension $d$ and $Z$ denotes the output space of size $k$. The posterior is defined as
$$P(Z|X) = \frac{P(X|Z)P(Z)}{P(X)}$$
where $P(Z)$ is the prior and $P(X|Z)$ denotes the likelihood (can be computed by neural network or some other model). The computation of $P(X)$ is hard (intractable) in high dimension.
$$P(X)=\sum_{Z}P(X|Z)P(Z)$$
I am not able of understand why computation of $P(X)$ is hard? I believe the hardness means time to compute it. When it is mentioned that $P(X)$ is intractable does it mean that time to compute the $P(X)$ is infinite or very large?

Well usually $p(x)$ is an integral over the parameter space that can prove impossible to compute in any reliable way due to the dimension of the space. Even in the case when $Z$ belongs to a finite set $\mathfrak Z$, the size of the set $\mathfrak Z$ may be too large for enumeration. Take for instance the case of the Ising model.

Thanks, impossible meaning it is going to take infinite time or finite time (very large)?

You may benefit from Googling "Nested Sampling" to read about practical difficulties in computing the normalisation factor P(X), sometimes called the Evidence.

"Intractability" has an exact meaning. Computational complexity is a keyword that will help here

There are also doubly intractable posteriors.

I think there are along the same line definitions in different places:

We say that a problem is intractable if there is no polynomial-time algorithm for the problem.

(Source: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/66intractability/)
Imagine $Z$ has n dimensions. That means the sum will look like:
$$P(X)=\sum_{Z_1}\sum_{Z_2}...\sum_{Z_{n}}P(X|Z)P(Z)$$
If there are $m$ different values in each sum, time to compute would be $m^n$. This is similar in computational approximations to the integrals. As $n$ increases, time to compute increases exponentially.


Exactly computing an integral is impossible, outside of rare cases with an explicit antiderivative.

One way to approximate an integral is to use a riemann sum. This requires a large amount of calculation which scales very poorly with dimensionality.

Other approaches to approximating an integral behave similarly to the Riemann sum: they require a large amount of calculation which scales very poorly with dimensionality.


Thus, in general, you are going to need a lot of calculation to compute an approximation of $P(X)$ and all other terms which are defined in terms of an integral. The situation is similar in discrete problems, unless the discrete space we are summing over is small enough.
I think this great paper, even though it is not written for mathematicians, provides a great point of view on the meaningful aspects of computational complexity: Why Philosophers Should Care About Computational Complexity, Scott Aaronson, 2011

Thanks for the answer. Is there any paper  with theoretical analysis on approximating of P(X)?

@Rma every algorithm for this approximation has a large body of litterature. The question is very complex since the details of the model also play a large role. There's no easy reference to dive into that complexity, sorry
